# Java Date which looks same in any timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am currently trying to get create a java Date which looks the same no matter what timezone I view it in.  My current code is:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2015, Calendar.JANUARY, 8, 0, 0, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Date date = cal.getTime();
```

In my current timeZone this gives me '2015-01-08T00:00:00Z'In another this gives me 2015-01-08T00:00:00-03:00.  What I want to know is if there is any way to drop the timezone part so as the time is the same in both time zones.

I would be VERY grateful for any help on this matter.  Thank you.

Comment: With Java 8 you can use a LocalDateTime.

Comment: I think you are looking for UTC time. So that client (who knows its timezone) converts UTC to local time.

Comment: Use JodaTime if you don't have Java 8. There are pretty much the same as Java 8's time package is based on JodaTime.

Comment: If I use UTC the time it will return in the second timeZone will be 3 hours behind the original hence the time will not be the same.  But thank you for your input.

Comment: `Date` objects don't store the timezone.  It's one of the many things wrong with the Date class.  `Calendar`, however, does...

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I cant use java 8 and im trying to restrict the use of any other API's I assume there is no easy way to do this then?

Comment: @user3781095 Please note that Oracle Java SE 7 is planned to go EOL on April 2015: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html
If you're using the Oracle JRE and don't have a support contract with Oracle then it's strongly recommended to upgrade to Java SE 8 by then.

Comment: @GauravGupta An UTC-time (as `java.util.Date` is just a holder for a Unix-timestamp counted in millisecs in UTC zone) must look different in different timezones when it comes to formatted output. OP really wants a plain representation of year, month, day, hour etc. WITHOUT timezone or offset. Absolutely no chance to realize this in Java-pre8 and without any external library. Well, the OP could just reinvent the wheel and write himself a `LocalDateTime` or `PlainTimestamp` class which is rather a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Java SE 8 comes with a new Date & Time API. Have a look at [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

Comment: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library also has the same kind of classes, to represent a general date-time value without any assigned time zone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the format of the time, create a java.text.SimpleDateFormat object to print your time in the format that you want.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

If you want the time to be printed with the same numbers no matter the TimeZone,
Use             String ids[] = java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
to get the TimeZone's IDs and find the ID that you want.

In this example, I created two SimpleDateFormat objects set to two different TimeZones.  They both print off the same Calendar object.  I have taken off the Z in ft2 to remove the time zone portion.  By relying on toString(), I think you would be subject to Locale differences in displaying dates, like US MM/dd/yyyy and UK dd/MM/yyyy.

```
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
        TimeZone tz2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
        Calendar acal = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat ft =  new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss  Z");
        ft.setTimeZone(tz);
        SimpleDateFormat ft2 =  new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
        ft2.setTimeZone(tz2);
        String date1 = ft.format(acal.getTime());

        System.out.println(date1);
        String date2 = ft2.format(acal.getTime());
        System.out.println(date2);
```

Output:

2015-01-08T10:36:39  -0500

2015-01-08T09:36:39